# Customize Dialog window prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have implemented the new DialogService as shown in this issue
[A New IDialogService for WPF](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1666)

However, this doesn't explain how to edit the window of the dialog itself, since the `NotificationDialog` is a `UserControl`.

I have tried changing it to a `Window` but then an exception is raised due to not being the root Window.

**Any idea how can I change the Window of the dialog?**

Since the Title and the Icon is set in `DialogViewModelBase`, I have tried to add a `ResizeMode` property as well.

In `DialogViewModelBase`:

```
private ResizeMode _resizeMode;
public ResizeMode ResizeMode
{
   get => _resizeMode;
   set => SetProperty(ref _resizeMode, value);
}
```

and in `NotificationDialogViewModel` implementation:

```
public NotificationDialogViewModel()
{
    Title = "Notification";
    ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanMinimize;
    CloseDialogCommand = new DelegateCommand(CloseDialog);
}
```

However it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how can I change the Window of the dialog?

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/428df870959a20c71f68f602e86f7e9eefc2db70/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs#L43), it looks like you have to implement `IDialogWindow` and override the default registration to the built-in implementation.

Also, you don't need to inherit from `DialogViewModelBase`, just implementing `IDialogAware` suffices.

Comment: Yes, creating a `DialogWindow` implementing `IDialogWindow` has worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

For others who search for this - the style can be set using `prism:Dialog.WindowStyle`.

Example from

<s>https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Sandbox/Wpf/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/Dialogs/NotificationDialog.xaml</s>

New link: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html#style-the-dialogwindow

```
<UserControl x:Class="HelloWorld.Dialogs.NotificationDialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             Width="300" Height="150">

    <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen" />
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
        </Style>
    </prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Button Command="{Binding CloseDialogCommand}" CommandParameter="True" Content="OK" Width="75" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" IsDefault="True" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Other properties can also be set using `Setter`. For example,

```
<Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
```

will hide the title bar.

Comment: How can i possibly change the window host layout to wrap the user control content inside BusyIndicator for example?

Comment: @FurqanSafdar I'm not sure I understand what you mean and I didn't work with WPF for a while anyway, you'd be better off asking a new question