# Change Owner of Prism DialogWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog, prism

I have implemented the new `IDialogService` in WPF using MVVM. My dialogs are working fine, for the exception that when I have another window open in the foreground, the dialog will appear in the center of that window.

What I want to achieve, is that the Dialog is always in the center of the Main Window. This could be applied by setting the `Owner` property of the `DialogWindow` (which is of Type `Window` and the `Parent` of the Dialog `UserControl` that I created) to `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

What I found out by now, is that it is possible to change the Style of the `DialogWindow` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840028/customize-dialog-window-prism). But I don't see any possibility to change the `Owner` property in that way.

I already tried to set the `Owner` property by accessing the `Parent` in the `UserControl` CodeBehind. But it is either null (`OnInitialized`) or cannot be changed, because 'the `DialogWindow` is already displayed' (`OnLoaded`/`OnApplyTemplate`).

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Prism dialog service sets the *first active window* as *owner* of a dialog by default. That is the way it is implemented. There are multiple ways to set the main window as owner with more or less effort and different constraints, but it requires some customization. It only took a month to write.

### Replace dialog window

You can define a new dialog host window by deriving it from `Window` and implementing `IDialogWindow`.

```
public class DialogWindow : Window, IDialogWindow
{
   public DialogWindow()
   {
      Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
      WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
   }

   public IDialogResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

Then register it in your container. This way **all dialogs** will be centered in the main window.

```
containerRegistry.Register<IDialogWindow, DialogWindow>();
```

You can also set the window startup location in the dialog window style, instead of the dialog window class.

```
<prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="Window">
      <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterOwner" />
   </Style>
</prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
```

This approach may be more interesting in later version of Prism, that may allow for registering multiple, named dialog windows. Then you could use the custom window in special cases and the default window otherwise.

### Custom dialog service

You can just copy the `DialogService` [implementation from Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/8b24d8ccaa691ff942ddeb67be95099ffb2fa698/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs) and adapt it to fit your needs. In the `ConfigureDialogWindowProperties` change the line that sets the owner window.

```
window.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
```

Replace the default active window with the main window.

```
window.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Do not forget to register the custom dialog service in the container to overwrite the default one.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDialogService, CustomDialogService>();
```

### Custom dialog service with attached properties

If you need a more custom behavior, consider making this ower logic parametrizable with [attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) that you can set on your user control and read in your custom dialog service. This is the most flexible approach, but also the one requiring the most effort. It allows for customization of each dialog individually.

```
public class WindowOwnerAttachedProperties
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMainWindowOwnerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMainWindowOwner", typeof(bool), typeof(WindowOwnerAttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false));

   public static bool GetIsMainWindowOwner(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
   {
      return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(IsMainWindowOwnerProperty);
   }

   public static void SetIsMainWindowOwner(DependencyObject dependencyObject, Window value)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(IsMainWindowOwnerProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Set the attached property in your dialog user control.

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Your.Namespace"
             ...
             attachedProperties:WindowOwnerAttachedProperties.IsMainWindowOwner="True">
```

Set the window owner depending on the attached properties like above in the custom dialog service.

```
if (window.Owner == null && WindowOwnerAttachedProperties.GetIsMainWindowOwner(dialogContent))
   window.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
else if (window.Owner == null)
   window.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
```

This lets you choose to use the default behavior for backwards compatibility or set the main window as owner for each dialog view individually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will test your suggestions during this week and give you feedback.

Comment: I copied the DialogService implementation and exchanged the line that sets the owner window and it is working like a charm. Thank you once again for your answer!